# Que signifie « adhérer immédiatement aux chiffres » dans cette phrase ?

Tags: sens

Durkheim se refusait à accepter l'explication la plus prudente, celle qui adhère immédiatement aux chiffres et selon laquelle les prétendues causes sociales seraient simplement des circonstances qui favorisent.

Comment: Durkheim, étant le père de la sociologie (on dit souvent) travaillait donc avec les statistiques.  Il ne faisait pas confiance aux statistiques à prémière vue....

Answer (score 4):

**Adhérer [immédiatement] aux chiffres** signifie correspondre aux chiffres, autrement dit, une explication que les chiffres valideraient, qui ne serait pas contredite par les chiffres.
Ici, le mot **immédiatement** renforce l'idée que les chiffres correspondent exactement à cette explication, et que par conséquent on la choisisse directement sans en chercher une autre

Answer (score 2):

Ici **adhérer** a le sens de *coller/s'attacher à*.
**Immédiatement** ici veut dire *directement, sans intermédiaire*.

Je pourrais reformuler ainsi : Durkheim n'acceptait pas dans un premier temps l'explication qui ne s'en tiendrait qu'aux chiffres/qui ne prendrait en compte que les chiffres.
Ceci dit ça me semble un peu contradictoire avec ce que je me souviens de la pensée de Durkheim mais je ne suis pas spécialiste.